# How to use ListView and onClickListener in a fragment?

Tags: java, android, listview, android-fragments

how would i add a listview and onclicklistener to my tab1fragment.xml layout?

i have multiple tabs but if i got one example i think i could work it out for the rest..  i have tried other answers but no success as of yet.

heres a look at my work..  thanks guys

> MyTrans.java

```
package com.storey.user.storeytom.fragments;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Vector;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.HorizontalScrollView;
import android.widget.TabHost;
import android.widget.TabHost.OnTabChangeListener;
import android.widget.TabHost.TabContentFactory;

import com.storey.user.storeytom.adapters.MyFragmentPagerAdapter;
import com.storey.user.storeytom.R;

public class MyTrans extends Fragment implements OnTabChangeListener,
        OnPageChangeListener {

    private TabHost tabHost;
    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private MyFragmentPagerAdapter myViewPagerAdapter;
    int i = 0;
    View v;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
                             @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tabs_viewpager_layout, container, false);



        i++;

        // init tabhost
        this.initializeTabHost(savedInstanceState);

        // init ViewPager
        this.initializeViewPager();


        return v;
    }

    // fake content for tabhost
    class FakeContent implements TabContentFactory {
        private final Context mContext;

        public FakeContent(Context context) {
            mContext = context;
        }

        @Override
        public View createTabContent(String tag) {
            View v = new View(mContext);
            v.setMinimumHeight(0);
            v.setMinimumWidth(0);
            return v;
        }
    }

    private void initializeViewPager() {
        List<Fragment> fragments = new Vector<Fragment>();

        fragments.add(new Tab1Fragment());
        fragments.add(new Tab2Fragment());
        fragments.add(new Tab3Fragment());

        this.myViewPagerAdapter = new MyFragmentPagerAdapter(
                getChildFragmentManager(), fragments);
        this.viewPager = (ViewPager) v.findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
        this.viewPager.setAdapter(this.myViewPagerAdapter);
        this.viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(this);

    }

    private void initializeTabHost(Bundle args) {

        tabHost = (TabHost) v.findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
        tabHost.setup();

        for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {

            TabHost.TabSpec tabSpec;
            tabSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Tab " + i);
            tabSpec.setIndicator("Tab " + i);
            tabSpec.setContent(new FakeContent(getActivity()));
            tabHost.addTab(tabSpec);
        }
        tabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {
        int pos = this.tabHost.getCurrentTab();
        this.viewPager.setCurrentItem(pos);

        HorizontalScrollView hScrollView = (HorizontalScrollView) v
                .findViewById(R.id.hScrollView);
        View tabView = tabHost.getCurrentTabView();
        int scrollPos = tabView.getLeft()
                - (hScrollView.getWidth() - tabView.getWidth()) / 2;
        hScrollView.smoothScrollTo(scrollPos, 0);

    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        this.tabHost.setCurrentTab(position);
    }
}
```

> Tab1Fragment.java

```
    package com.storey.user.storeytom.fragments;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.storey.user.storeytom.R;
public class Tab1Fragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
                             @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab1fragment, container, false);
        return v;
    }
}
```

> tab1fragment.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:text="Fragment 1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

> tabs_viewpager_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TabHost
        android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <HorizontalScrollView
                android:id="@+id/hScrollView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fillViewport="true"
                android:scrollbars="none" >

                <TabWidget
                    android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
                </TabWidget>
            </HorizontalScrollView>

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" >

                <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                    android:id="@+id/viewPager"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
            </FrameLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </TabHost>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: @0x0nosugar thanks for the reply, ive edited to try and make it less broad

Answer (score 0):

You can add a `ListView` below the `TextView` like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:text="Fragment 1" />


    <ListView
        android:id="+@id/myList1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     />
</LinearLayout>
```

For a list, you don't need an `onClickListener` which would only react to clicks on the list (never mind where exactly). You want an `onItemClickListener`, which you can set in the `onCreateView()` method of the `Fragment`:

```
ListView lvList1 = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.myList1);
lvList1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener{... });
```

For a tutorial for `onItemClickListener` see [this link](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html#listview_adapterlistener).

Comment: Thanks for the great answer on the list, it works!

but regarding the onItemClickListener, how would i get "textView1" to open a new activity? as i see on the guide it only activates a toast, Thanks!